# Append paths to HttpUrlConnection in Java

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

Can we create a connection with base URI using java HttpUrlConnection, and append resource paths to connection later?

Eg:

```java
URL baseUri = new URL("http://localhost:9090");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.appendUrl("/file-repo/list") // NEED THIS
```

If yes, Pls provide an example.

Comment: No. Just create a new `URL` and `HttpURLConnection` from it. If you're worried about connections, it already does connection pooling behind the scenes.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne So what I expect here is not possible?